# Bluestacks: failed to install bluestacks. error: value cannot be null. parameter name: path1

Tags: bluestacks

I am getting this error. I uninstalled previous version of bluestacks but after the uninstall completed,

**failed to install bluestacks. error: value cannot be null. parameter name: path1**

I can't install the new version of it.

Log file shows:

```
2015-08-08 12:28:22.316000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386: Opened log file
2015-08-08 12:28:22.322000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     1 INFO CLR version 2.0.50727.8662
2015-08-08 12:28:22.323000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     1 INFO IsAdministrator: False
2015-08-08 12:28:22.332000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     3 INFO the tag File  directory is C:\Users\IT\Downloads\BlueStacks-ThinInstaller (1)\
2015-08-08 12:28:22.356000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     1 ERROR Failed to check for version. err: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\BlueStacks' is denied.
2015-08-08 12:28:22.356000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:    at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
2015-08-08 12:28:22.356000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:    at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, RegistrySecurity registrySecurity)
2015-08-08 12:28:22.356000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:    at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey)
2015-08-08 12:28:22.356000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:    at BlueStacks.hyperDroid.ThinInstaller.ThinInstaller.AbortIfAlreadyInstalled()
2015-08-08 12:28:22.365000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     1 INFO HandleCreated
2015-08-08 12:28:22.366000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     1 INFO Handle: 199170
2015-08-08 12:28:22.368000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     1 INFO m_ClassName = WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d
2015-08-08 12:28:22.369000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     1 INFO Launching in installer mode
2015-08-08 12:28:24.456000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340: Opened log file
2015-08-08 12:28:24.460000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO CLR version 2.0.50727.8662
2015-08-08 12:28:24.460000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO IsAdministrator: True
2015-08-08 12:28:24.461000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO In installer mode
2015-08-08 12:28:24.461000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO className = WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d
2015-08-08 12:28:24.461000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO Got handle: 199170
2015-08-08 12:28:24.464000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO Checking for existing BlueStacks installation...
2015-08-08 12:28:24.464000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO arg[0] = install:WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d
2015-08-08 12:28:24.467000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     3 INFO the tag File  directory is C:\Users\IT\Downloads\BlueStacks-ThinInstaller (1)\
2015-08-08 12:28:24.487000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO s_ParentHandle = 199170
2015-08-08 12:28:24.487000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO Populating Default Engilsh Strings
2015-08-08 12:28:24.488000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO Successfully Stored Localized Strings
2015-08-08 12:28:24.488000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO Successfully Populated English Strings
2015-08-08 12:28:24.489000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO SPAWNAPPS_APP_NAME = 
2015-08-08 12:28:24.489000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO Setting directory permissions
2015-08-08 12:28:24.659000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO Checking for existing BlueStacks installation...
2015-08-08 12:28:26.076000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO Showing next screen
2015-08-08 12:28:26.933000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO Inside ShowInstallScreen
2015-08-08 12:28:26.937000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO Showing Install screen
2015-08-08 12:28:26.938000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO Inside Next Clicked
2015-08-08 12:28:26.938000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO Showing P2DM options screen
2015-08-08 12:28:26.938000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO P2DM is currently not enabled
2015-08-08 12:28:27.861000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO Starting installation...
2015-08-08 12:28:27.865000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     1 INFO Checking for existing BlueStacks installation...
2015-08-08 12:28:27.905000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     5 INFO The campaign name is empty
2015-08-08 12:28:27.906000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     5 INFO Starting installation with msiexecArgs: /i "C:\Users\IT\AppData\Local\Temp\BlueStacks_lai2pu14.dka\BlueStacks_HD_AppPlayerSplit_setup_0.9.30.4239_REL.msi" /qn  P2DM=1 FEATURES=268435455 OEM=BlueStacks APPPLAYER=YES CAMPAIGNNAME=empty LAUNCHER=ThinInstaller COMMONDATAFOLDER=C:\ProgramData APPNOTIFICATIONS=1
2015-08-08 12:28:27.937000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     5 INFO Waiting for installer to complete...
2015-08-08 12:28:31.351000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     5 INFO Installer exit code: 0
2015-08-08 12:28:31.351000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     5 INFO Will try to send message 1025 to 199170 
2015-08-08 12:28:31.351000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     1 INFO Received message WM_USER_START_AGENT
2015-08-08 12:28:31.352000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     5 INFO Starting Agent
2015-08-08 12:28:31.352000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     5 ERROR System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
2015-08-08 12:28:31.352000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386: Parameter name: path1
2015-08-08 12:28:31.352000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
2015-08-08 12:28:31.352000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:    at BlueStacks.hyperDroid.ThinInstaller.ThinInstallerUi.StartAgent()
2015-08-08 12:28:31.353000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     1 INFO Processed message WM_USER_START_AGENT
2015-08-08 12:28:31.354000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     5 INFO product name
2015-08-08 12:28:31.356000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     5 INFO Creating runtime uninstall entry
2015-08-08 12:28:31.359000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     5 ERROR Failed to create uninstall entry. err: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
2015-08-08 12:28:31.359000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340: Parameter name: path1
2015-08-08 12:28:31.359000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
2015-08-08 12:28:31.359000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:    at BlueStacks.hyperDroid.ThinInstaller.ThinInstallerUi.CreateRuntimeUninstallEntry()
2015-08-08 12:28:31.361000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     5 INFO Returning from DoApkToExeStuff
2015-08-08 12:28:31.363000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     5 INFO Will try to send message 1030 to 199170 
2015-08-08 12:28:31.363000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     1 INFO Received message WM_USER_LAUNCH_FRONTEND
2015-08-08 12:28:31.364000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     6 INFO Launching frontend
2015-08-08 12:28:31.364000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     6 ERROR Unhandled Application Exception:
2015-08-08 12:28:31.364000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     6 ERROR System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
2015-08-08 12:28:31.364000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386: Parameter name: path1
2015-08-08 12:28:31.364000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
2015-08-08 12:28:31.364000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:    at BlueStacks.hyperDroid.ThinInstaller.ThinInstallerUi.LaunchFrontend()
2015-08-08 12:28:31.364000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:    at BlueStacks.hyperDroid.ThinInstaller.ThinInstallerUi.<HandleMessages>b__2c()
2015-08-08 12:28:31.364000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:    at BlueStacks.hyperDroid.ThinInstaller.ThinInstallerUi.<>c__DisplayClass35.<PerformAction>b__34()
2015-08-08 12:28:31.364000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
2015-08-08 12:28:31.365000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
2015-08-08 12:28:31.365000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
2015-08-08 12:28:36.611000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1386:     7 INFO the tag File  directory is C:\Users\IT\Downloads\BlueStacks-ThinInstaller (1)\
2015-08-08 12:28:36.876000 BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.9.30.(1340:     5 INFO In SleepAndExit with 0
```